# C# UdpClient.Connect() raises exception on 2nd call

Tags: c#, networking, udp

I tried to send form a single `UdpClient` to several different open UDP sockets from localhost to localhost. However in the first version only the first message of the loop was sent, the rest did not even make it out.

When trying to isolate the error the second call to `udpClient.Connect()` raises a `SocketException` pointing to the Error `WSAEISCONN 10056`

The official documentation of `UdpClient.Connect()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.connect?view=net-6.0) states in the remark section if you want to send to different endpoints, call `Connect` again. However this is the opposite of what the error tells me.

So is this just an error in the docs of the `Connect` methode, or do I miss something here?

Too fast requests should not be an issue with only 3 requests every 3 Seconds and as I use the normal `Send(buffer)` call, there should be no packets waiting to be sent to the previous endpoint.

Simple example to reproduce (I used .net 6, Win10):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace UdpClientIssue;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sender = CreateSender(3_000, 40001, 40002, 40003);
        var reciverA = CreateReciver("ReciverA", 40001);
        var reciverB = CreateReciver("ReciverB", 40002);
        var reciverC = CreateReciver("ReciverC", 40003);

        reciverA.Start();
        reciverB.Start();
        reciverC.Start();
        sender.Start();

        sender.Join();
    }

    static void Reciver(int port)
    {
        var localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
        using var listener = new UdpClient(localEP);
        var buff = new byte[1024];

        while (true)
        {
            var senderEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.None, 0);
            var data = listener.Receive(ref senderEP);
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine($"Recived at {port}: {message}");
        }
    }

    static void Sender(int interval_ms, params int[] ports)
    {
        int messageNumber = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(interval_ms);
            using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
            {
                foreach (var remotePort in ports)
                {
                    var message = $"Message {++messageNumber} to {remotePort}";
                    var sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sending to {remotePort}: {message}");

                    var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, remotePort);
                    //This errors on second iteration
                    //udpClient.Connect(remoteEP);
                    //udpClient.Send(sendBuffer);

                    //This works
                    udpClient.Send(sendBuffer, remoteEP);
                }
            }
            messageNumber += 100 - ports.Length;
        }
    }

    static Thread CreateReciver(string name, int port)
    {
        var ts = new ThreadStart(() => Reciver(port));
        var t = new Thread(ts)
        {
            Name = name
        };
        return t;
    }

    static Thread CreateSender(int interval_ms, params int[] ports)
    {
        var ts = new ThreadStart(() => Sender(interval_ms, ports));
        var t = new Thread(ts)
        {
            Name = "Sender"
        };
        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's error in the docs. Description of this error message says:

> Socket is already connected.
> A connect request was made on an already-connected socket

And source code explicitly throws this exception with this error code if socket was already connected.

[Here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Sockets/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs,829) you see it just forwards connect to `Socket`:

```
public void Connect(IPEndPoint endPoint)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();

    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(endPoint);

    CheckForBroadcast(endPoint.Address);
    Client.Connect(endPoint);
    _active = true;
}
```

And in `Socket.Connect` you [see](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Sockets/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,802) it throws this errors if socket is already connected:

```
if (_isConnected)
{
    throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.IsConnected);
}
```

Fortunately you already know the better way of doing this - just pass remote endpoint to `Send` call. UDP is connectionless protocol anyway so calling `Connect` only sets default remote endpoint and doesn't perform actual connection.